# PHP query to database returning empty JSON data

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I have a query to my pgsql table which should return several responses. In fact, it does in pgAdmin. However, when I run it through php and convert to lat, long using google apis I am getting empty brackets in the response. Does anyone see what I may be doing wrong, it was working up till yesterday and I was doing some tweaking to the code. I may have inadvertently done something wrong.

Here is the query and subsequent conversion in php...

```
$address = pg_query($conn, "
SELECT 
  CONCAT(incident.city, ' ' , incident.state_1)
FROM 
fpscdb001_ws_001.incident
WHERE
incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Upgrade' AND
incident.status_1 = 'staging' AND
incident.site_id != '2RS'
;");

if (!$address) {
      echo "Query failed\n";
      exit;
    }
$arr = array();
while ($coordsred = pg_fetch_row($address)){
$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$coordsred[0]."&sensor=true";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
$status = $xml->status;
if ($status=="OK") {
    $Lat = (float)$xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
    $Lng = (float)$xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
    $arr[] = array("lat" => $Lat, "lng" => $Lng);
}
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

This is the companion javascript that calls the php...

```
var xhrred = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrred.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (xhrred.readyState == 4) {
var arrred = JSON.parse(xhrred.responseText);
console.log(xhrred.responseText);
if(Array.isArray(arrred)){
showMarkersRed(arrred);
}
}
}
xhrred.open('GET', 'markersred.php', true);
xhrred.send();
```

Comment: Have you verified that the API call is working? It doesn't output anything if `$status` is not "OK", and you've initialized `$arr` to an empty array. So if it doesn't work, you'll just get an empty array as output and no error. Maybe add an `else` to indicate if the status isn't OK.

Comment: I have, with a generic address.

Comment: Usually *City* and *State* are comma-separated. Also try adding a column alias to query.